# Siri-like Shadow on Scroll

Tags: objective-c, uiview, shadow, siri

In Apple's [siri](/questions/tagged/siri) for iOS, when Siri answers a question and it doesn't fit on the whole screen a user can scroll through the information. What is interesting about the scroll/table view in Siri is that when information extends beyond the bounds of the scroll/table view, a subtle gradient appears on the bottom of the view:

[image: Siri with and without a shadow]

How does Siri detect that the information in the scroll / table view extend beyond its bounds? I know how easy it is to fade in an image with a shadow, but I don't understand how the detection of the content works?

Is there any kind of documentation or class that Apple provides that will let me detect this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably just a matter of setting the content size according to the content that you load and then testing whether the scroll view height is less than the content view height.